# Generate a double click mouse event in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, double-click

I am trying to generate a double click mouse event on the EDT as follows:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
            component,                                      
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK,
            x, y,
            2, // click count
            false
        ));
    }
});
```

This does not seem to dispatch a double click event, even though I am setting the click count to 2.

Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: What is `component`?  In fact, don't bother to answer that.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (which will answer that, as well as 4 out of 5 of the other questions I might ask).

Comment: Faking events is usually a bad idea. Why don't you move the code that handles the doubleclick into a separate method and call that method directly?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is it for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Considering:

```
final JButton clickTwiceButton = new JButton();
final JButton fireEventButton = new JButton();
```

Listeners:

```
clickTwiceButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Double clicked!");
        }
    }
});

fireEventButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Invoking later for no reason, just to simulate your code
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                clickTwiceButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
                     fireEventButton,
                     MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                     1,
                     MouseEvent.BUTTON1, 
                     0, 0, 
                     2, 
                     false
                ));
            }
        });
    }         
});
```

When I click `fireEventButton` the `MouseEvent` gets correctly dispatched to `clickTwiceButton`, and the dialog appears as expected.

So, as @Andrew pointed out, the problem seems to be that either you are firing the event to the wrong component or that something is not right with the registered `MouseListener` / `MouseAdapter` code.

Use [component.getMouseListeners()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMouseListeners%28%29) to check for your component Listeners and debug the code that handles its events.

Comment: +1 for using the `EventQueue`; @user1246353 should also consider using [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: Hi @trashgod, it is nice to see you again. 1+ for the Robot suggestion. Just one thing (I'm too lazy to open a new question, but I think this is correlated to the OP question), since the event is being dispatched directly from a Listener, wouldn't it run on the `EventQueue` anyway? I'm never sure about when I really need `invokeLater` and `invokeAndWait`.

Comment: Good question: not necessarily; we aren't shown how the OP's `Runnable` is evoked. As long as `actionPerformed()` runs on the EDT, `invokeLater()` ensures that the `MouseEvent` will be dispatched _after_ the `ActionListener` completes. Looking closer, I see that I overlooked the OP's similar usage, so +1 for `@Override`!

Comment: @Anthony Accioly nice answer +1

Answer (score 1):

The method is very simple. You should get the time of the first click and the time of the second click, then you can do a condition in between.
Method code as below:

```
private boolean state=false;
private long first_pressed;
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("add");
btnAdd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            
            if(state==false) {
                first_pressed=e.getWhen();
                state=true;
            }
            if(first_pressed!=e.getWhen())
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"doubel click","Click",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                state=false;
            }
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class TestMouseListener implements MouseListener {    
      private boolean leftClick;
      private int clickCount;
      private boolean doubleClick;
      private boolean tripleClick;
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
            leftClick = true; clickCount = 0;
            if(evt.getClickCount() == 2) doubleClick=true;
            if(evt.getClickCount() == 3){
                doubleClick = false;
                tripleClick = true;
            }
            Integer timerinterval = (Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");

                     Timer  timer = new Timer(timerinterval, new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 

                            if(doubleClick){
                                System.out.println("double click.");                                    
                                clickCount++;
                                if(clickCount == 2){
                                    doubleClick();   //your doubleClick method
                                    clickCount=0;
                                    doubleClick = false;
                                    leftClick = false;
                                }

                            }else if (tripleClick) { 

                                System.out.println("Triple Click.");
                                clickCount++;
                                if(clickCount == 3) {
                                   tripleClick();  //your tripleClick method
                                    clickCount=0;
                                    tripleClick = false;
                                    leftClick = false;
                                }

                            } else if(leftClick) {                                      
                                System.out.println("single click.");
                                leftClick = false;
                            }
                        }               
                    });
                    timer.setRepeats(false);
                    timer.start();
                    if(evt.getID()==MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) timer.stop();
        }           
  }


      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        JTextField component = new JTextField();
        component.addMouseListener(new TestMouseListener());
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.add(component);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);

        component.addMouseListener(new TestMouseListener());
      }
```

}